# catDog string problem at Codingbat.com

Tags: java, string

Could anyone check my solution?

I want to return true if the string "cat" and "dog" appear the same number of times in the given string. There are various strings with different numbers of "cat" and "dog".

```
public boolean catDog(String str) 
{  
  int catAnswer = 0;
  int dogAnswer = 0;
  int cat_Count = 0;
  int dog_Count = 0;

  for (int i=0; i< str.length()-1; i++) 
  {
    String sub = str.substring(i, i+2);


    if ((sub.equals("cat")))  cat_Count++;
    if ((sub.equals("dog")))  dog_Count++;
    catAnswer = cat_Count; 
    dogAnswer = dog_Count;

  } //end for

  if(dogAnswer == catAnswer ) {return true;}
  // else
  return (dogAnswer != catAnswer);
}
```

UPDATE:

1. If i use i + 3 i get an error code
   Exception:java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
   String index out of range: 7 (line
   number:10) - hence i use i + 2 (no
   errors are reported with it
2. Changing to i < str.length() - 4 gives a blanket response of true
   despite some of the test strings
   containing an unequal number of
   "cat" & "dog " tokens

The crux of the problem is that the response is either all true or all false when there is variable numbers of "cat" & "dog" in the various strings

the output from the code can be seen at http://codingbat.com/prob/p111624 - catDog string problem

Please try in cutting and pasting my code to see the output - this will explain more graphically than i could say

Comment: Before you solve that, you need to solve the problem of how to phrase a question.

Comment: Arg, I tried my best to save and transform the question actually into a question.

Comment: @Anthony: You were editing it as the same time as me...and we were both doing it while other people were closing the question.  :)

Comment: @Beska: We tried but epically failed. :/

Comment: This question should be re-opened now that it has been edited into shape. (It actually should never have been closed in the first place.)

Answer (score 5):

While you are pretty close to a solution, there are a few critical problems in your code:

1. Your call to `substring()` fetches a string of size `2`. That string can *never* be `cat` nor `dog`. Change the second parameter in the method call to `i + 3` to get `3` characters.
2. Your call to `substring()` will throw an `IndexOutOfRangeException`, as `i` approaches the end of the length of the input string. Make sure you do not ask for a substring that "overflows" the length of the input string. One way to fix this bug, would be to change the conditional expression in your `for` loop to `i < str.length() - 2`.
3. The return value of your method will always be `true`. In the case where `dogAnswer != catAnswer` you return exactly that expression - which will resolve to `true`. A possible solution: Merge the two `return` statements into `return dogAnswer == catAnswer`.

Additionally, there are a few things you could do to make your code simpler:

1. There really is no need to copy `cat_Count` into `catAnswer` and `dog_Count` into `dogAnswer`. Throw away two of the variables, and use the other pair exclusively.
2. <del>If the input string is not allowed to contain anything else than `cat` and `dog`, your loop can be optimized to only consider every third position in the input string. Change `i++` into `i += 3`.</del> (Update: after seeing the test data used at [CodingBat](https://codingbat.com/prob/p111624), I can tell that this is not the case.)

After implementing fix #1, #2 and #3 as well as suggestion #1, I have made a test run using the provided [test bench](https://codingbat.com/prob/p111624), and the result is quite  satisfying:

## [image]

All correct

Comment: Rats, you beat me. I'd typed up pretty much the same answer but didn't refresh the page quick enough.

Comment: The loop limit should not be `str.length() - 4`, it should be `str.length() - 2`. Otherwise you'll miss a cat or dog appearing at the very end of the string.

Comment: mmyers: Nope. str.length() - 3 should be the last index. Think of the string "cat". Do you want to call "cat".substring(1, 4) ?

Comment: @mmeyers: Heh, I started typing up my answer just after casting my vote to reopen, as a compensation for the early close. I really have no idea how I ended up at `str.length() - 4`, but at least it is fixed now, thanks to you :)

Comment: @roryparle: Note the use of "explicitly less than" `<` in both the original code and the answer. Using `<=` and `3` might make the code more obvious though.

Comment: @roryparle: I did test it before commenting, just in case I'd made an off-by-one error.

Answer (score 1):

```
int count(String needle, String haystack) {
  return haystack.split(needle, -1).length - 1;
}

public boolean catDog(String str) {
  return count("dog", str) == count("cat", str);
}
```

Here's an "All Correct" solution that uses `split`. The `-1` is used to preserve trailing empty strings.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to iterate each character in your string and then check to see if the substring is equal to either cat or dog and increments the counts.

```java
public boolean catDog(String str) {

  int end = str.length();
  int cDog = 0;
  int cCat = 0;

  // We don't need to go to the end because cat/dog are 3 characters long each. So we can avoid extra checks.
  for (int i=0; i < end-2; i++) {
        if(str.substring(i, i+3).equals("cat")) {
          cCat++;
        } else if(str.substring(i, i+3).equals("dog")) {
          cDog++;
        }  
   }

   return cCat == cDog ? true : false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.
if i use i + 3 i get an error code Exception:java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 7 (line number:10) - hence i use i + 2 (no errors are reported with it
2.changing to i < str.length() - 4 gives a blanket response of true despite some of the test strings containing an unequal number of "cat" & "dog " tokens

The crux of the problem is that the response is either all true or all false despite there being a variable numbers of "cat" & "dog" tokens in the various  strings

the output from the code can be seen at http://codingbat.com/prob/p111624 - catDog string problem

Please try in cutting and pasting my code to see the output - this will explain more graphically than i could say

Comment: You'd do better to edit your post and add information, rather than adding an answer. I've already done that, but what you can do _now_ is delete this answer before _it_ gets downvotes....

Comment: @stanny: `i < str.length() - 4` was a blunder by me, and it has been fixed (see comments on my answer). You will get exceptions if you follow my advice #1 alone. Implement #2 as well to make the exceptions go away, and #3 to get the right return values.

Comment: @Michael Todd: Looks like he's lost the cookie, so he can't edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

A solution with less duplication would be to write a function that counts occurrences of a substring within a string, then call that function with the string and "cat", and with the string and "dog", and return whether the two counts agree.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean catDog(String str) {
    int cdog = 0;
    int ccat = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length()-2; i++)
    {
        if (str.charAt(i)== 'c' && str.charAt(i+1)== 'a' && str.charAt(i+2)== 't')
        {
            ccat++;
        }

        else if(str.charAt(i) == 'd' && str.charAt(i+1)== 'o' && str.charAt(i+2)== 'g')
        {
            cdog++;
        }

    }

    if (cdog == ccat)
        return true;

    else
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean catDog(String str) {
  boolean x =false;  // created a boolean variable.
  int cCount=0;    // variable to count cat in string.
  int dCount=0;    // variable to count dog in string.
  for(int i =0;i<str.length()-2;i++){
    if(str.charAt(i)=='c'&&str.charAt(i+1)=='a'&&str.charAt(i+2)=='t'){ // checking if the string has cat if it does count how many time it has.
      ++cCount;
    }
    if(str.charAt(i)=='d'&&str.charAt(i+1)=='o'&&str.charAt(i+2)=='g'){  // checking if the string has dog if it does count how many time it has.
      ++dCount;
    }
  }
  if(cCount==dCount){  // comparing cat and dog count.
    return true;
  }
  return x;
}
```

Comment: we can also use str.substring(i.i+3) instead of charAt() method to check cat and dog appearance in string.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean catDog(String str) {

  int countcat = 0;
  int countdog = 0;

  if( str.length() >= 3){
  for( int i = 0 ; i < str.length()-2 ; i++){
  if ( str.substring(i,i+3).equals("cat"))
  countcat = countcat + 1;
  }


  for( int j = 0 ; j < str.length()-2 ; j++){
  if ( str.substring(j,j+3).equals("dog"))
  countdog = countdog + 1;
  }}

  if (countdog == countcat )
  return true;


  return false;

}
```

Comment: You should explain why this solves the problem, not just post code.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean catDog(String str) {
    int cat, dog;
    cat = 0;
    dog = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; i++) {
        if ((i + 3) > str.length()) {
            break;
        }
        if (str.substring(i, i + 3).equals("cat")) {
            cat++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; i++) {
        if ((i + 3) > str.length()) {
            break;
        }
        if (str.substring(i, i + 3).equals("dog")) {
            dog++;
        }
    }
    if (cat == dog) {
        return true;
    } else
        return false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer. It works well. Hope it helps if you're stuck.

```html
public boolean catDog(String str) {
  int cat = 0 ;
  int dog = 0 ;
  for(int i  = 0 ; i < str.length()-2; i++){
    String temp = str.substring(i,i+3);
    if(temp.compareTo("cat")==0)
      cat++;
     if(temp.compareTo("dog")==0)
      dog++;
  }
  return cat==dog?true:false;
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean catDog(String str) {
    int count=0;
    int flag=0;
    for (int i=0; i<str.length()-2; i++)
    {
        if (str.length()>=3&&str.substring(i,i+3).equals("cat"))
            count++;
        if (str.length()>=3&&str.substring(i,i+3).equals("dog"))
            flag++;
    }

    if (count==flag)
        return true;
    else 
       return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean catDog(String str) {

  return str.replace("cat","@@").length()==str.replace("dog","&&").length();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My simple python solution:

```
def cat_dog(str):
  
  cat_sum, dog_sum = 0, 0
  for i in range(len(str)-1):
    if str[i:i+3] == 'cat':
      cat_sum += 1
    elif str[i:i+3] == 'dog':
        dog_sum += 1
  if dog_sum == cat_sum:
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
#String-2 > cat_dog(pyton 3)
def cat_dog(str):
    c_c=0
    c_d=0
    for i  in range(len(str)-2):
        if str[i:i+3]=='cat':
            c_c+=1
        if str[i:i+3]== 'dog':
            c_d+=1
    return c_c==c_d
```

Answer (score 0):

This helps:

```
def cat_dog(str):
    return str.count('cat')==str.count('dog')
```